# How do i bind and invoke`function type` in android data binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I've a variable of type `(position: Int) -> Unit` and I want to invoke the method from xml like this `android:onClick="@{theMethod.invoke(someInt)}`

Is it possible?, then How can I do it ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The way I went about it is as follows. The method you have will correspond to the class `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1`. so the idea is to declare this in the XML as such:

```
<data>
    <import type="kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1"/>
    <import type="kotlin.Unit"/>

    <variable
        name="theMethod"
        type="Function1&lt;Integer, Unit>"/>
</data>
```

It doesn't look pretty, but it works. We import what we want and then declare a binding variable of the type we want. Note that the character `<` is illegal when trying to define generic types, so we use `&lt;`.

Now it should be easy to use. I do it like:

```
android:onClick="@{_ -> theMethod.invoke(someInt)}"
```

The method signature for `onClick` requires us to pass in a method that receives one parameter of type `View`. I'm not interested in using it, so I declare it as `_` in the lambda I pass to the `onClick`. Then inside the lambda I invoke the method I want.

I always make an effort not to put logic inside the XML, but I allow myself these kind of shortcuts, since I don't really think of them as business logic.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you fred for the answer. It really helped me.

Comment: @theapache64 you should accept this is the correct answer :)

Comment: Thanks dude! Nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

Use the lambda form

```
android:onClick="@{() -> theMethod.invoke(someInt)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#listener_bindings) suggests another way with prettier syntax:

Create a class with necessary functions:

```
class Presenter {
    fun compeleteChange(task: Task, isChecked: bool){}
}
```

Import to xml:

```
 <data>
   <variable
        name="presenter"
        type="my.location.Presenter" />
</data>
```

Use it like:

```
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:onCheckedChanged="@{(cb, isChecked) -> presenter.completeChanged(task, isChecked)}" />
```

This way, you can you functions with custom signature.